# what is better to inner of session start of using outer function in security risk?

Tags: php, html, security, session, cookies

I trying to development a chance of better security, using both `cookie` and `session`.

Perhaps in php, session must be initiation first before can be called,

What better between using inner function to called `session::start()` or calling `session::start` separately ?

```
session::start();
function function_name(){...}
```

or

```
function function_name(){
session::start();
...
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I did not understand the question? Are you asking if it's better a function itself to call `session_start()`?

Comment: I already give more explanation about this case.

Comment: first one is better, because otherwise you will result into multiple calls of session start

Comment: @RoyalBg that any clue to prevent multiple session start ?

Comment: Function definitions don't cause anything to actually execute so both examples given are effectively the same.

Comment: @GordonM yes, they are, unless you are going to call 2 functions in one execution of code. It's just error prone. If you have `function funcOne() { session_start(); } function funcTwo() { session_start(); }` you could not be sure that you will not call both functions in one file. Also, it's breaking the single responsibility principle and causing side effects. A function e.g. named `display_content()` is not supposed to start a session. An user will not know it. One will rely on the func name and call it, then call `display_age()` and break the app with 2 session starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to put `session_start();` at the top of your page before any other code.

However, if you are includes configuration related files then it's best to put `session_start();` at the very top of a file that is included in all files.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on functions that you feel they should start a session is a code smell not only about the sessions, but the whole code design.

First of all, an application is supposed to have ONLY ONE entry point. Each other functionality you'll later need after entering the entry point is the last one's responsibility to call it.

If you have a bunch of functions that you are going to call from the global scope means that you do not have an entry point and each part of the page needs to reinitialize the state of the application upon loading. Thus, leading to init bunch of code, including `session_start()` at every page.

Which, I guess, makes you feel that you need to extract that repeatable code, including `session_start()` into functions.

Sadly, this could result into code like:

```
function get_user_details() {
    session_start();
    $query = Db::query("SELECT id, username, email FROM users WHERE id = " . $_SESSION['id']);
    return Db::fetchAll($query);
}

function get_user_news() {
    session_start();
    $query = Db::query("SELECT name, title FROM news WHERE userid = " . $_SESSION['id']);
    return Db::fetchAll($query);
}
```

This might seem cool to you and you might have a page `user_details.php` where you call the first function and respectively `user_news.php` where you are calling the second function. They both might work.

But! You may need a page, let's say `overview.php` where you need both user details and user news. Then you will call both functions in one place, resulting into calling `session_start()` twice.

Which at least will result into a notice error (but it may raise in much worse error) : `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()`

And, once you are going to code not for yourself, but with other people in your team, they will not know the behavior of the function.

A function has to do one thing, and it should be explained from its name and return type.

If I know that a function returns `array` and is called `get_user_info`, I will automatically assume it will query the database to return assoc array with the user info. And would NEVER EVER GUESS that there is EVEN A SLIGHT CHANCE this function to initialize a session.

So, in other words, a function MUST NOT cause ANY side effects.

To prevent this, you should return to the start of my post, where I said there should be only one entry point.

Whether an MVC-like architecture where a `index.php` controls everything and the router is dispatching to what page to call, or, just a include-like system, where each file includes e.g. `app.php` where at the top of it there is `session_start()`.

P.S.: I know the thread was about security function, but it has nothing to do with the whole concept, that's why the examples are not related with any security feature like login/register/etc/ I guess the examples given could be more understandable.

P.P.S.: In the terms of security the same rules apply. Your function should not initialize session, it should only manipulate it in order to set the session, cookie, all the things you think your security would need and the session has to be started from the entry point. This would also be good, if you, or any other teammate, by mistake, try to call the function from wherever outside and the session is not started, it will not work and throw errors, giving you the opportunity to understand you are calling it from the wrong place and not all of your resources are initialized.

Comment: Whole your answer was wrong

Comment: @SuryaTanamas what makes you think that way? Even it might not helped you, it does not necessarily mean it's wrong

Comment: Actually I have explained you why you may cause yourself a lot of headache initializing the session in the function, rather than initializing it first and call the function later.

Comment: It's about inner function or outter function. Your answer was a mash, as i guest. @royal bg answer is corectly at all

Comment: You just didn't understand it